# One of my website page is not being responsive in mobile

Tags: plugins, responsive-design, custom-wordpress-pages

hope you are all ok .

I am getting a problem with my website https://upfoto.nl. All content of my website is responsive and functioning ok except - https://upfoto.nl/contestants/test-60/ - this page. it's responsive in tablet version but not in mobile, in mobile, it's getting off-centered. Please help me to fix it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a quick look at it, looks like you have put `width: 100%;` on your class **wpvc_contestant_values** when going in mobile. That makes the content as big as the screen. Removing that resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, But it's not working I Changed the value in many ways, Its same.